# Get Line Number of Method in class and method name

Tags: java, android

I am developing custom logging component in android,i want to get the method name,line number and class name,i tried with StackTraceElement,but i could able to get only the method name and line number from where it is called,the scope of StackTraceElement is only within the method where it is called but i need to print the method name and line number of all methods in class,can anyone help me in doing this?

Comment: for class name u can use getClass()

Comment: there are several StackTraceElement in a stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

For the class name

```
this.getClass().getName();
```

should be enough.

For line number I found

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber();
```

and the method would be

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()
```

Remember to access the right element from the array from the `getStackTrace()`.

Answer (score 0):

For any one new visiting with the same query ,
Java 9 and above has additional functionality just for this purpose called [StackWalker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.html)

```
List<StackFrame> stack =
StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE).walk((s) -> 
s.collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println("All frames : \n" + stack.toString());
```

Also refer tutorial at

[StackWalkerExample](https://dzone.com/articles/jdk-9-stackwalker)